# DynamoDB Node.js Update Item Results in 'ValidationException' Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been trying to update an item within a DynamoDB table for the past 4 hours and nothing that I've read from their documentation works.

I am essentially trying to create a counter for each request, however I get the 'ValidationException' error every single time I try to run this script with Lambda.

See anything wrong?

```
function updateReqCount(companyKey,companyId) {
  const paramsKey = {
    TableName: 'api-keys',
    Key: {
      "APIKey": companyKey,
      "companyId":companyId
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set requests = requests + :r",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":r": 1
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  }

  docClient.update(paramsKey, function(err, keyData) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(keyData, null, 2));
    }
  });
}
```

The error:

```
2018-03-20T18:15:15.644Z    a2f8cd79-2c6a-11e8-b347-670f9ee49d61    Unable to update item. Error JSON: {
"time": 1521569715644,
"code": "ValidationException",
"retryable": true,
"requestId": "IHDQSD5RSULLAFMULR1G6AMUONVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
"statusCode": "400",
"_tubeInvalid": false,
"waitForRecoveryBeforeRetrying": false,
"codeSeq": [
   3,
   37,
   38,
   39
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Please provide the full message contained in the exception.

Comment: @jarmod Added error.

Comment: This code works perfectly for me with a table whose primary partition key is APIKey, primary sort key is companyId, and the 'requests' attribute exists within the updated item and that attribute is of type Number. Check those first. The error response that you provided is unusual. Which region is your table in?

Comment: @jarmod It is very odd, I've worked with DynamoDB a lot for REST APIs, first time I've ever seen this happen. I am in US-WEST-2. (Oregon)

Comment: Works fine in us-west-2 for me. If I deliberately provoke an error (e.g. if the requests attribute is absent or it's of type string) then I always get a ValidationException that includes a message and that message is very clear and accurate. You are not getting any message at all, which is odd. Are you using an up to date AWS JavsScript SDK?

Comment: Are you using DAX (DynamoDB Accelerator)? Suspect that may be important.

Comment: And are you sure that your runtime credentials have correct (write) permissions on the DynamoDB table?